# saving a captured image to external storage failed

Tags: java, android

I want to save my captured images to a specific directory (/sdcard/DCIM/FokusStacker) with the following method. I have tried different Locations, but none of them worked.

```java
private void capturePicture(){
        File dir = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/FokusStacker");
        String fileName = "IMG_"+ System.currentTimeMillis();
        File file = new File(dir,fileName);
        Log.d(TAG, "capturePicture: DIRECTORY: "+dir.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions =
                new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onImageSaved: SAVED");
                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: FAILED");
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

These are the Permission i've included:

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And i also tried saving it to the internal storage.

Code Snippet for to get the local directoryof the App for the `file`:

```
File dir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
```

Can anyone please guide me how to do this?

I am a little new to android so please, I would appreciate if I can have a detailed procedure.

Comment: What goes wrong? Errors? Exceptions? And what is `ImageCapture` ?

Comment: dont really know what goes wrong, i only get the `log.d FAILED` , so i asume the onerror method is called.

`imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().build();`

Comment: FAILED is your own message. You should log exception.getMessage() as it will tell you . And i dont know what ImageCapture would be. Never heard of.

Comment: Thanks a lot this tip is exellent for debugging. it says "Failed to write temp File"

ImageCapture is part of CamerX libary to take images and videos

Comment: Thank u so much it work now!!!!